# Regex find link without any protocols and add // at the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

Please use this link: https://regex101.com/r/KKpn4A/2
I need regex which can find href="example.com" and replace to: href="//example.com". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use 'Edit' under your post and use the formatting avaiable. It's a mesh to read your comment.

Comment: Do u want output like this ? `<a href="//zpl://screen?pid=5a81768c83c07a9d14fd249c&sid=5bb23572c67397295cddba51" target="_blank">zpl://screen?pid=5a81768c83c07a9d14fd249c&sid=5bb23572c67397295cddba51</a> <a href="//zpl://screen?pid=5a81768c83c07a9d14fd249c&sid=5bb23572c67397295cddba51" target="_blank">link</a> <a href="//example.com"; target="_blank">example.com</a>; <a href="//example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You need String.replace function of JavaScript. Use this regex:

```
/href=\"(?!\/)/g
```

It simply cheecks for `'href="'` NOT followed by a `'/`'.

Now replace with:

```
"href=\"//"
```

That will replace as you want.

**Edit**:

If you want to keep links starting '`zpl://`', you can use this regex:

```
href=\"(?!/)(?!zpl://)
```

The replacement string is the same.

**Edit2:**

Now I have added a check for '`https?//`' so it also ignores if it's a normal link, starting with '`href=\"http://`' or '`href=\"https://`':

```
/href=\"(?!\/)(?!zpl:\/\/)(?!https?:\/\/)/g
```

**Edit3** - Ignore all protocols:

```
/href=\"(?!\/\/)(?!\w+?:\/\/)/g
```

Comment: Please use this link: https://regex101.com/r/KKpn4A/2 I need regex which can find href="example.com" and replace to: href="//example.com". Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second regex I gave you will do just that.

Comment: `href=\"(?!/)(?!zpl://)`

I added it: https://regex101.com/r/KKpn4A/3

Works fine, only one additional question: I want to keep any links starting from `zpl://` or `http://` or `https://` or whatever. So only if we see href="domain" and domain doesn't contain `://` we will replace it.

Comment: About Edit2. You are right. Is it possible to create regex which can avoid all possible protocols? (not only hardcoded: http, https, zpl) Something like: href="string_value" If string_value contain `://` this href should be skipped. I want to find any href entries which don't contain `://` inside string_value. Hope I explained it clear more or less. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this.  You would test first if the url has the protocol with the regular expression `/^[^.\/]*\/\//`.

The first `^` must match the beginning of the string only.  The next part `[^.\/]*` matches the protocol (including colon) if there is one, i.e. any prefix that doesn't include a '.' or '/' character.  The next part `\/\/` matches the two '/' characters that come after.

If this regular expression matches, you don't need to make any changes to the URL.  Otherwise, you need to add your two slashes to the beginning.

```
function addSlashes(url) {
  return /^[^.\/]*\/\//.test(url) ? url : `//${url}`;
}
```

Let's test the function on your provided code.

```js
function addSlashes(url) {
  return /^[^.\/]*\/\//.test(url) ? url : `//${url}`;
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach((aTag) => {
      const url = addSlashes(aTag.getAttribute('href'));
      aTag.setAttribute('href', url);
      aTag.textContent = url;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="zpl://screen?pid=5a81768c83c07a9d14fd249c&sid=5bb23572c67397295cddba51" target="_blank">zpl://screen?pid=5a81768c83c07a9d14fd249c&sid=5bb23572c67397295cddba51</a></li>
  <li><a href="link" target="_blank">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">https://example.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="example.com" target="_blank">example.com</a></li>
</ul>

<button>Change URLs</button>
```

Comment: Please use this link: https://regex101.com/r/KKpn4A/2 I need regex which can find href="example.com" and replace to: href="//example.com". Thanks in advance.